# How to use Data Model Variables with underscores in Spring data Mongo DB?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am working on a Web project with Spring Boot and Spring Data with Mongo DB.
I have a Model Class called Employee with variable names with underscores.I have written a method to get the count of a field from DB using group by but when i execute the application i m getting error as 
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property person found for type Employee!

```
TypedAggregation<Employee> studentAggregation = 
Aggregation.newAggregation(Employee.class,              Aggregation.group("customer","person_Type","project_Location").count().as("total"),Aggregation.project("customer","person_Type","project_Location",
                       "total"),Aggregation.sort(Direction.ASC,"customer"
                       ,"person_Type","project_Location"));

AggregationResults<Employee> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(studentAggregation, Employee.class);
```

Employee Data Model:

```
@Document(collection = "employee")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    public long emp_id;
    private String work_Geography;
    private String work_Country;
    private String work_Location;
    private String customer;
    private String project_Location;
    private String person_Type;
}
```

Comment: Which version of SpringData MongoDB are you using? And could you please add the structure of the `Employee` class.

Comment: @ChristophStrobl updated the question with Employee Data model...I am using <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version> spring-boot-starter-parent

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug ([DATAMONGO-2339](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2339)) in the handling of properties with underscores that has been resolved in *Lovelace SR 11* aka *Spring Data MongoDB 2.1.11*. Please upgrade.